# IIS Virtual Directory triggers "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

Tags: iis

I have added to my IIS8 site a virtual directory (**\ANTERGOS1\data\heizungskeller**) that points to a Samba share residing on a different server. Trying to access the content through a browser, however, triggers the HTTP Error 500.19 ("**Cannot read configuration file \?\UNC\ANTERGOS1\data\heizungskeller\web.config**"). What might be the issue? Do I need to add IUSR to the users of the Samba share? If so, with which password as I understand that IUSR is devoid of a password?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself! The "advanced options" of the Virtual Directory allow to impersonate a specific user rather than the standard IUSR. See picture. [image]